# EventFiring Listeners for selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Listeners in selenium C# framework and how to access predefined Loggers methods from eventhandler in code as mentioned in java we have two objects one is Eventfiringwebdriver and other one is eventhandler now both the objects are to be registered like this:

```
EventFiringWebDriver eventDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);

EventHandler handler = new EventHandler();
eventDriver.register(handler);
```

but in C# I've used the code similar to the above code postedbut Im not able to register the two objects can you please provide me enough knowledge about this

this is the link I got the information about handling Listeners in java but I want in C# 
http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/event-listener/

Answer (score 2):

EventFiringWebDriver has several delegates/events for actions like clicked, opened etc.
 Here an example how you can add several listeners to the event.

```
eventDriver.ElementClicked += HandlerMethodName1;
eventDriver.ElementClicked += HandlerMethodName2;
```

[msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx)